# MAGMA-question concerning the transformation of a $kG$ -module $M$ into a right ideal of the group algebra

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, magma

Let $G$ be a finite group and $k$ be a finite field of characteristic $p>0$ such that $p\mid |G|$.

Let $M$ be a $kG$-module which has an embedding $M\hookrightarrow kG^{reg}$ into the regular $kG$-module $kG^{reg}$.

Then $M$ corresponds to a right ideal of $kG$.

**Question:**

> Is there a MAGMA command / procedure that has as input the $kG$-module $M$ and as output the corresponding right ideal $I$ in terms of giving me elements of the algebra $kG$ that generate $M$ as the right ideal $I$?

I only could find how to get a basis of the module $M$ in the manual, but not how to transform this into the elements of the algebra $kG$.

More specifically, I am in the following concrete situation:

Let $P$ be a non-trivial $p$-subgroup of $G$. Let $T$ be the trivial group.

Consider the $kP$-module $M:= k \uparrow_T^{P}\cong {kP}^{\text{reg}}$.

$M$ is a permutation module. Hence, $k_P$ is a submodule of $M$ (namely, $\{\lambda\cdot (1,1,1,\dots , 1)^t | \lambda\in k\} \cong k$, if $M$ is given as a representation via permutation matrices).

Since $kG$ is free as $kP$-module, the induction functor is exact.

Thus, via induction, we get the $kG$-module $N:=k\uparrow_P^G$ as a submodule of $M\uparrow_P^G\cong {kG}^{\text{reg}}$.

I would like to get $N$ (and all of its direct summands) as a right ideal of $kG$ and couldn't find out how to do this in MAGMA.

Cross-reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3848128/magma-question-concerning-the-transformation-of-a-kg-module-m-into-a-right-i

I would be very grateful for any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you construct the module homomorphism $N\!\!\uparrow_P^G  \rightarrow M\!\!\uparrow_P^G$ as a Magma homomorphism, i.e. with the hom<X -> Y : [images of generators of X]>  syntax? If so, you should then be able to compose with a chosen isomorphism of $M\!\! \uparrow_P^G$ with the group ring. (Since GModule doesn't work on group algebras, you might have to construct this as a linear isomorphism.) This construction also makes it clearer (at least to me) that there won't be a canonical embedding: maybe this could be brought out more in the question.

Comment: More generally for $H$ an arbitrary subgroup of $G$, $k{\uparrow_H^G}$ is the right ideal $H^+kG$ of the group algebra $kG$. Here $H^+$ is the sum of the elements of $H$ in $kG$. So if you let $T$ be a transversal to $H$ in $G$, then $\{H^+t\mid t\in T\}$ is a basis for your module, in $kG$. Is this what you need?

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments. I don't know how to construct the induced homomorphism in MAGMA. $\langle \{H^{+}t | t\in T\}\rangle$ is what I need, but I would like to have it as a submodule of the regular module $kG$ in MAGMA, but as a GModule, and then construct an isomorphism to $\langle \{H^{+}t | t\in T\}\rangle$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand completely what you are trying to do, but I get the impression that the heart of the problem is that you are given $kH$-module homomorphism $M \to N$, and you want to compute the induce homomorphism $M_H^G \to N_H^G$. I think the following code does that.

```
InducedHom := function(phi, G)
  //phi:M->N is a KH-module M->N homomorphism with H <= G
  //Compute induced homomorphism Induction(M,G) -> Induction(N,G)
  M := Domain(phi); N := Codomain(phi); K := BaseRing(M);
  H := Group(M);
  IM := Induction(M,G); IN := Induction(N,G);
  ind := Index(G,H);
  dm := Dimension(M); dn := Dimension(N);
  images := [];
  for i in [1..ind] do
    for j in [1..dm] do
      imseq := [K!0 : k in [1..(i-1)*dn]] cat Eltseq(phi(M.j)) cat
               [K!0 : k in [1..(ind-i)*dn]];
      Append(~images, IN!imseq);
    end for;
  end for;
  return hom<IM->IN | images>;
end function;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Yes, sorry for the confusion, I am lacking MAGMA code exactly for computing the induced homomorphism. In your code, what are dm and dn?

Comment: Oh that's strange - there were two lines missing. I copied and pasted, so I am not sure how that happened. Try again!

Comment: Ok, now it works, thank you very much!

Comment: In an ideal world, the tensor product and homomorphism operators on modules would be treated as functors, and all of their associated homomorphism operators available. But unfortunately the world is not ideal and often one has to supply these missing facilities.